# How do I create a dictionary in Java?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I am curious as to how to create a dictionary in Java. I know that Python had a dictionary setup similar to `dictionary = {"key": "something"}`.
I know there are other ways to do this in Java, such as creating two synchronized lists and using the same position in each list to mimic a dictionary.

```
ArrayList<Object> keys = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
public void add(Object key, Object value){
    keys.add(key);
    values.add(value);
}
// And a subsequent return function
public Object getValue(Object key) {
    return values.get(keys.indexOf(key));
}
```

However, this screams to me bad programming. Is there a simpler syntax to do it with a single statement? Most questions already asked about the subject are closed and, consequently, of little help.

Comment: Use a `java.util.Map` [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: Why don't you use a database instead? As you're dealing with thousands of words.

Comment: @Azad: He means dictionary as in a key/value pair collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Java uses HashMaps instead of dictionaries.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Some other Maps include [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).  The difference is in the backend (one uses a hash table, the other uses a Red-Black tree)

Example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
....

Map<String,String> mMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
mMap.put("key", "something");
Iterator iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can use `HashMap` like so:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

For example, now you could use this `map` object much like you would a dictionary in Python.

```
map.put("Key", "Value");
System.out.println(map.get("Key"));
```

There are several other classes that implement the `Map` interface that are useful for utilizing a Dictionary in Java (some are better to use in certain situations than others).

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative for Dictionary in Java is HashMap.
You can refer to Oracle's Documentation for Further References.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

If you're concerned about performance, you should try TreeMap. I assume that you care more about retrieval time than insertion one.

Answer (score 1):

For concise map creation (and a lot of other useful things), I recommend [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). In particular, see [ImmutableMap.of](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) and [ImmutableMap.Builder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html).

Examples:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    "one", 1,
    "two", 2,
    "three", 3
);

Map<String, Integer> map = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
    .put("one", 1)
    .put("two", 2)
    .put("three", 3)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

A word may contains more than one meaning. so you can use MultiMap.

```
    MultiMap dictionary = new MultiValueMap();
    dictionary.put("key", "something");
    dictionary.put("key", "Important");
    System.out.println("dictionary Value : "+dictionary.get("key"));
```

dictionary Value : [something, Important]